# Analyse DMARC reports

Tags: email, text-processing, xml, dmarc

I receive [Google's DMARC reports](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10032472?hl=en) daily as a zip file containing an XML file. I manually download each zip file `~/Documents/DMARC`.

I want to aggregate the information from all the saved DMARC reports and produce a human-readable readable report (e.g. table in LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet). I would rather not have memory-hungry or CPU-hungry services running all the time.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

**Background Info**

Domain-based Message Authentication, Reporting and Conformance (DMARC) is an evolving [technical standard](https://dmarc.org/resources/specification/) and the DMARC report format is specified by that standard. It also looks like Ubuntu [natively support DMARC](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man8/dmarcts-report-parser.8.html), but I need detailed instructions.

The Google link above shows samples of input DMARC XML file format
and an output tabular form. As requested, they are pasted here.

Sample input XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<feedback>
  <report_metadata>
    <org_name>solarmora.com</org_name>
    <email>noreply-dmarc-support@solarmora.com</email>
   <extra_contact_info>http://solarmora.com/dmarc/support</extra_contact_info>
    <report_id>9391651994964116463</report_id>
    <date_range>
      <begin>1335571200</begin>
      <end>1335657599</end>
    </date_range>
  </report_metadata>
  <policy_published>
    <domain>bix-business.com</domain>
    <adkim>r</adkim>
    <aspf>r</aspf>
    <p>none</p>
    <sp>none</sp>
    <pct>100</pct>
  </policy_published>
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>203.0.113.209</source_ip>
      <count>2</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>fail</dkim>
        <spf>pass</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>bix-business.com</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>bix-business.com</domain>
        <result>fail</result>
        <human_result></human_result>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>bix-business.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
</feedback>
```

Sample output table:
[image: Sample output table:]

Comment: @Jaydin did you ever find a simple solution for collating XML DMARC reports into a spreadsheet? There seem to be many large scale processing solutions (including this open source option written in python: https://domainaware.github.io/parsedmarc/index.html) but they are excessive for a lot of situations.

Comment: @SuprMan, yes, I got it working for my use-case two years ago. My solution had many steps for the initial setup and no one else seemed to be interested in this question, so I didn't bother posting the answer. Let me know if you're interested and I see if I can find my notes and post it.

Comment: It's true that this question hasn't gotten many views but I would certainly be interested in your solution. I suspect the question may gain interest because large email service providers seem to be cracking down on messages that lack DAMRC recently.

Comment: @SuprMan I added my answer below. Please have a look and let me know if it works for you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the steps I used with Ubuntu 22.04 for my use-case. I expect they can be improved upon for more general use, so please comment and let me know, and I will do my best to adapt the solution.

This solution will use the [dmarcts-report-parser package](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/dmarcts-report-parser.8.html) and [mysql server](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/databases-mysql) from the Ubuntu default repository. The final output is a csv file, so this solution is probably best suited for light users (e.g. one or two domains) and occasional users of DMARC aggregation reports.

Here is a sample of the output CSV file in LibreOffice Calc (around half the columns displayed):
[image: output csv file]

---

## Preparations

1. **Download DMARC aggregation reports**: Download the DMARC aggregation report attachments from the emails. These files usually end with `.xml.gz` or `.zip` and there is no need to extract them as dmarcts-report-parser will do that for you.

   - Note: The dmarcts-report-parser could be configured to download the DMARC reports from an IMAP server. I did not use that functionality due to security concerns.
   - Hint: In addition to manually downloading DMARC report attachments, it is also possible to automate this using Google Apps Script (I use this), Microsoft Power Automate, and various email client add-ins.
2. **Create working folders**: For the purpose of this exercise, I will create a folder called `dmarcprocess` to contain the config files and the final csv file output, and a subfolder called `Reports` to store the downloaded DMARC aggregation reports from step 1.

   - Open a terminal
   - `mkdir ~/Documents/dmarcprocess`
   - `cd ~/Documents/dmarcprocess`
   - `mkdir Reports`
   - Copy all the dmarc reports into the `Reports` folder

---

## Setup MySQL Server

1. **Install MySQL**: This step assumes that mysql server is not already installed.

   - `sudo apt update`
   - `sudo apt install mysql-server`
   - Check msql server is active: `sudo service mysql status` (use Ctrl-C to exit). The response should say `Active: active (running)`. If not active, try `sudo systemctl start mysql`.
   - Recommended: `sudo systemctl disable mysql` to stop mysql from auto starting at PC boot and using system resources. You can use `sudo systemctl start mysql` to manually start and `sudo systemctl stop mysql` to manually stop the mysql server.
   - Note: mysql server is installed with default settings, which aren't very secure (e.g. no password for `root` user). You may want to change these setting later if you intend to auto start mysql server at boot.
2. **Create database and user**: We will create the default database and default user for dmarcts-report-parser. These can be customised later.

   - `sudo mysql -u root -p` to log into the mysql server and then press enter at "Enter password:" prompt, as there is no `root` password. The below commands need to be entered at the `mysql>` prompt. I have also included how the server should respond to each command.
   - `CREATE DATABASE dmarc;` to create a new database called dmarc. Server response: `Query OK, 1 row affected`.
   - `USE dmarc;` to connect to the newly created database. Server response: `Database changed`.
   - `CREATE USER 'dmarc'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';` to create a new user. Server response: `Query OK`.
   - `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dmarc.* TO 'dmarc'@'localhost';` to give the new user full access to the new database. Server response: `Query OK`.
   - `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` to reload the permissions. Server response: `Query OK`.
   - `quit;` back to the terminal.

---

## Setup dmarcts-report-parser

1. **Install dmarcts-report-parser**

   - `sudo apt install dmarcts-report-parser`
2. **Configure dmarcts-report-parser**: Copy the sample config file into the working folder and then edit it. Make sure you are in the `~/Documents/dmarcprocess/` folder for the below commands.

   - `cp /usr/share/doc/dmarcts-report-parser/examples/dmarcts-report-parser.conf.sample ./dmarcts-report-parser.conf` copies and renames the sample config file.
   - `sed -i "s/'dbhost'/'localhost'/" ./dmarcts-report-parser.conf` changes the name of the mysql server to `localhost`.

---

## Setup tables and export view

1. **First run of dmarcts-report-parser**: The first run of the dmarcts-report-parser will create the database tables and then populate the database using the dmarc reports previously downloaded.

   - `dmarcts-report-parser -z ./Reports/*`
   - The system should respond with `Adding missing table <report> to the database.` and `Adding missing table <rptrecord> to the database.` This means that the two database tables that dmarcts-report-parser needs were created.
   - Note: `-z` is for reading zip files according to the [project page.](https://github.com/techsneeze/dmarcts-report-parser?tab=readme-ov-file#usage) I found that this option works for both `.zip` and `.xml.gz` files. Strangely, this option is not currently documented in the [Ubuntu man page.](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/dmarcts-report-parser.8.html) Other potential file types are mbox (`-m`), MIME (`-e`) and xml (`-x`).
2. **Create a database View**: A database view simplifies the export of data.

   - `sudo mysql -u root -p` to log back into the mysql server and then press enter at "Enter password:" prompt, as there is no `root` password. The below commands need to be entered at the `mysql>` prompt. I have also included how the server should respond to each command.
   - `USE dmarc;` to connect to the newly created database. Server response: `Database changed`.
   - `CREATE VIEW exportview AS SELECT * FROM rptrecord INNER JOIN report USING (serial);` to create a new View called *exportview* from the two tables that the dmarcts-report-parser populated.
   - `quit;` back to the terminal.

## Export data and subsequent usage

1. **Export data**: The below command will export dmarc data using into the file `dmarc-report.csv`. It assumes you are in the `~/Documents/dmarcprocess/` folder.

   - `mysql --user='dmarc' --password='password' --batch --execute='SELECT * FROM dmarc.exportview;' | sed 's/\xml.*/xml/;s/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/' > ./dmarc-report.csv`.
   - Mysql will complain with `mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.` but that warning will not affect the outcome of the above command.
   - The new file `dmarc-report.csv` is a CSV file that can be opened and analysed with a spreadsheet app (e.g. LibreOffice Calc).
   - This command uses the MySQL Command-Line Client to connect to the database, export the view it tsv format. Then `sed` removes the xml output and then converts the reminder to csv format.

     - `--execute=` [execute the following statement and returns the result](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html).
     - `--batch` [print results using tab as the column separator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html). This option could be excluded as `--execute` seem to do the same thing by default.
     - `sed 's/\xml.*/xml/;` removes all text after "xml". This is needed because one of the database columns (raw_xml) contains the raw xml data which makes it difficult to convert into CSV format. Please let me know if anyone has a better method.
     - `s/\t/","/g;` replaces all tabs with a `,`.
     - `s/^/"/;` inserts a `"` at the begging of each line.
     - `s/$/"/'` inserts a `"` at the end of each line.
2. **Subsequent use**

   - I don't need mysql to run all the time, so I use `sudo systemctl disable mysql` to stop mysql from auto starting at reboot.
   - I use a bash batch file to automate parsing and import of new reports and the export the results.

     - `sudo systemctl start mysql` to start the mysql server
     - `dmarcts-report-parser -z ./Reports/*` to parse the reports and store them in the database
     - `mysql --user='dmarc' --password='password' --batch --execute='SELECT * FROM dmarc.exportview;' | sed 's/\xml.*/xml/;s/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/' > ./dmarc-report.csv` to export file.
     - `sudo systemctl stop mysql` to stop the mysql server after the export is finished.
   - At the moment I export all contents each time, but at some point I will probably modify the export statement to only export out the data I need while fine-tuning the dmarc, dkim and spf settings.
   - The Ubuntu man page implies that [dmarcts-report-viewer](https://github.com/techsneeze/dmarcts-report-viewer) will be supported in the future by the default repository. I intend to update this answer once that happens.

**PLEASE HELP IMPROVE THIS ANSWER by proving feedback in the comments.**

Comment: Since you wanted "feedback in the comments", the first thing I noticed is that installing MySQL is the opposite of "I would rather not have memory-hungry or CPU-hungry services running all the time". If possible, that app should be mode to use SQLite

Comment: @DanielT thanks for the feedback. You make a good point and I added another dot point under 'Subsequent use' to show how to stop and start the server. Unfortunately, the dmarcts-report-parser project page only states MySQL and PostgreSQL as being supported.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more lightweight solution:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os.path

addresses = {}

dirname = os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/DMARC")
for basename in os.listdir(dirname):
    if not basename.endswith(".xml"):
        continue
    tree = ET.parse(os.path.join(dirname, basename))
    row = tree.find("record/row")
    ip = row.find("source_ip").text
    current = addresses.setdefault(ip, { "count": 0, "dmarc_pass": 0, "dmarc_fail": 0, "dkim_pass": 0, "dkim_fail": 0, "spf_pass": 0, "spf_fail": 0 })

    current["count"] += int(row.find("count").text)
    policy = row.find("policy_evaluated")
    dkim_pass = policy.find("dkim").text == "pass"
    spf_pass = policy.find("spf").text == "pass"
    current["dkim_pass" if dkim_pass else "dkim_fail"] += 1
    current["spf_pass" if spf_pass else "spf_fail"] += 1
    current["dmarc_pass" if dkim_pass and spf_pass else "dmarc_fail"] += 1

print("ip_address,email_volume,dmarc_pass,dmarc_fail,dmarc_rate,spf_pass,spf_fail,dkim_pass,dkim_fail")
for ip, current in addresses.items():
    dmarc_pass = current["dmarc_pass"]
    dmarc_fail = current["dmarc_fail"]
    print(f'{ip},{current["count"]},{dmarc_pass},{dmarc_fail},{dmarc_pass/dmarc_fail}%,{current["spf_pass"]},{current["spf_fail"]},{current["dkim_pass"]},{current["dkim_fail"]}')
```

Save it to `dmarc.py` , `chmod +x dmarc.py` . Run it with `./dmarc.py > dmarc.csv` . I only guessed how the DMARC XML file format is supposed to work, so this may need adjusting.

#### Sample output

```
ip_address,email_volume,dmarc_pass,dmarc_fail,dmarc_rate,spf_pass,spf_fail,dkim_pass,dkim_fail
203.0.113.209,2,0,1,0.0%,1,0,0,1
```

[image: sample output csv libreoffice]